# How does Windows detect it is online?

Tags: windows, networking

I always assumed that Windows assumes that it is on the Internet when there is a default gateway.

Turns out this is not the case!

How does it judge, it is on the Internet? Does it "[phone home](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Phoning_home)"?

Comment: Why not use a passive tap (or monitoring port on the switch) and use wireshark to watch what flows in and out of the machine? Seems a lot better than guessing.

Comment: @John Gardeniers, yes - but then I would not give the kind people on serverfault a chance to express themselves on this matter, right? :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As documented at

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc766017(WS.10).aspx

`nslookup dns.msftncsi.com` followed by `HTTP GET www.msftncsi.com/ncsi.txt`

Comment: wget: unable to resolve host address `msftncsi.com'   Isn't that weird then?

Comment: That is strange, works for me http://msftncsi.com/ncsi.txt

Comment: Works for me too now. OK, weird, but then DNS always had a touch of black magic over it: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/09/podcast-68/